# Same transition matrix implies markov chain.

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

Let $X_i$ , $i \geq 0 $ be discrete time and state stochastic process.

Suppose that $P(X_n = j | X_{n-1} = i) $ does not depend on $n$. that is
$$P(X_n = j| X_{n-1} = i) = P(X_1 = j | X_0 = i) $$ for all $n$.

I want to know wheter this $X_n$ is Markov chain.
 I think that it is not Markov.

Since 
$P(X_2 =j |X_1= i, X_0 = x_0) = \frac{P(X_2 = j, X_1=i| X_0=x_0)}{P(X_1 =i | X_0 = x_0)}$,
if it is markov chain, then it must be that $P(X_2 = j, X_1=i | X_0=x_0) = P(X_2=j|X_1=i)P(X_1=i|X_0=x_0)$.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I edited

Comment: If this were a Markov chain then it would significantly simplify the standard definition of "Markov chain" (at least for the time-homogeneous case).  So, that alone suggests it is not.  The conditional independence of history (given the current state) is what is lacking here.  What if all transitions are dependent on what happens in the first transition?

Comment: I do not see any intuitive or technical reason why $\{X_n\}$ should be a Markov chain.